# Log the innerText of a created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make my script only log the strings once. So when a new string is created it will only log the new strings... This script logs all of the strings at once. I would like to find a way to make it only log the `.innerText` of freshly created children in that element with the id "team_log_actual".

Children can be added at any point of time.

Here is my script:

```javascript
setInterval(function() {
var logelement = $('#team_log_actual');
var foo = document.getElementById('team_log_actual');
for (let i = 0; i < foo.children.length; i++) {
    //console.log(foo.children[i].innerText);
    var PRINTactions = foo.children[i].innerText;
    var PRINTactionsEle = foo.children[i];

    var fields = PRINTactions.split(/ /);
    var Username = fields[2]; //grabs the second field from the splitted string. which is the username..
    var text1 = fields[3];
    var text2 = fields[4];
    var text3 = fields[5];
    var text4 = fields[6];
    var text5 = fields[7];
    var text6 = fields[8];
    var text7 = fields[9];
    var text8 = fields[10];
    var text9 = fields[11];
    var text10 = fields[12];
    //Defined multiple just in case. Each field will contain a string. If one is there, but it's highly unlikely to go past 5-6.
    var combinetext = fields[3] + " " + fields[4] + " " + fields[5] + " " + fields[6] + " " + fields[7];
    if (combinetext.includes("used item") == true) {
        console.log(Username + " : " + combinetext) // log the Username and the combinedtext. Only if the combinetext includes the string "in ejector".
    }
}
}, 10000); // Run every 10 seconds.
```

Comment: by working with Set object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Can children also be removed at any point in time?

Comment: Instead of setInterval, how about [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using MutationObserver. Recommended by user: CodeWalker

```js
// Solved code.
var Logconsole = document.getElementById('team_log_actual');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
        
            //This var gets the innertext of the new element.
            var TextFromNewElement = mutation.addedNodes[i].innerText;
            console.log(TextFromNewElement);
        }
    });
});
observer.observe(Logconsole, {
    childList: true
});







//Test code. ----- Create a fake element every 5 seconds.
var testelement = document.createElement('div');
testelement.id = 'team_log_actual';
testelement.innerHTML = '<p> <b>[<span style="color: #0FF">USER:</span>] <bdi style="color: #0FF;">User2</bdi></b> harvest a plant.</p>'

 setInterval(function(){
 
 //every 5 seconds, add the test element.
Logconsole.appendChild(testelement)
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="team_log_actual" class="log">
    <p> <b>[<span style="color: #0FF">USER:</span>] <bdi style="color: #0FF;">User1</bdi></b> planted a seed.</p>
</div>
```